# Twitter / Facebook integration

Tags: facebook, twitter, windows-phone-7

I am on a mid way of porting an iPhone application to Windows Phone 7. In that iPhone application it is providing provision for submitting score details through Facebook / Twitter mail etc. So I need to implement the same functionality in WP7, too. How can I implement this functionality in my Windows Phone project?

While searching I found some methods with the help of web browser. But that is not useful in my case. In my app I need to log in through the the designed page and need to update the score status to the social networks through my own view.

Please help me to achieve the functionality in my app. (If anybody has sample apps or links please attach that information, too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to post to facebook, twitter msn etc.

```
ShareStatusTask shareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask();
shareStatusTask.Status = "My Score: xxxx";
shareStatusTask.Show();
```

Comment: ShareStatustask??? By sing this how i can connect to twitter / Facebook etc?? And more over the isv is provided oath key, client secret etc for posting... then what is the relevance of that information?? In this form where i will get login related stuffs???

Comment: With the ShareStatusTask you don't need to login. The message you want to post is passed to the OS which then uses the accounts set up by the user to post to the appropriate network. This greatly simplifies the whole process. I do have code to do this manually as I have twitter/facebook integration in my app but with the new version I will be switching to this class. Let me know if the ShareStatusTast won't work for you and I will update my answer.

Comment: I just thought that maybe you need to post to an app twitter/facebook account instead of the end-users account. Is this what you need?

Comment: ok i will try this thing.. no problem . you told you tried this thing manually in your app. can you please share that information with me. I am asking this, only for updating my knowledge base. Dont feel bad on me... I am trying for the same for a couple of days.. bcs of that i am very much curious to get the knowledge...if u feel bad i m extremely sorry. Thanks for the new information that u already delivered. stezz

Comment: @BillReiss No problem :) The only reason to avoid this would be if you make use of all the extra parameters in facebook (videos, images etc).

Comment: @stezmaSebastian Don't worry, if you never ask for help how will you learn :) There is a lot of code required for doing this - too much to post here. Get in touch through twitter (@forty3degrees) and I will try and put something together for you.

Comment: Maybe if you use the ShareLinkTask and set the LinkUri property to the image url (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask(v=VS.92).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for, but [ScoreLoop](http://scoreloop.com) provides a free high score system as well as social network integration for Windows Phone games. I'm currently migrating my homegrown scores systems to ScoreLoop, looks good so far.